# Best practice for modal popup information page

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an app where I want to click a button and up pops a modal information page, with text and diagrams. Each information page will have react/js since the content is dynamic. I have about 30 different information pages that I want to create and 30 different buttons to trigger each page.

What is the best way of doing this? Do I create 30 different files with the html for each modal popup and do it that way?

I am using Material UI. Not sure which modal option I should be using. They have Dialog, Drawer, Menu or Popover. Or perhaps another method is better.

I figure this must be a common requirement so hopefully I can find the best practice.

Comment: [Dialog](https://material-ui.com/components/dialogs/) seems to be best for this. If you have 30 "different" contents (that goes inside a dialog), then you need to create 30 dialogs. But, as always, you should [not repeat the code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) i.e. take out common parts and create common (reusable) components.